# custom font in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to add custom font for Arabictext, which is loading its content from firebase database

```
private static class NamesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView Arabictext, Englishtext, Translationtext;


    public NamesHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        Arabictext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.arabicTextView);
        Englishtext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.meaningTextView);
        Translationtext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.translationTextView);
    }


}
```

Comment: add your font file to assets folder. and set typeface as:
Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "your_font_name");
texview.settypeface(tf);

Comment: I tried that, but to use this code I need to remove "static". if I removed static then application crashes

Comment: can you provide more code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font-name.ttf");
Arabictext.setTypeface(tf);
```

You need to put your custom font in `app/src/main/assets/fonts/` folder.

Comment: I tried that, but to use this code I need to remove "static". if I removed static then application crashes

Comment: @Mohammed_Muzaffar can you try `getContext().getAssets()` for the first parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You were using Adapter so which activity/fragment  has called this adapter has to pass context to it in constructor

```
public MyAdapter(Context mContext){
 this.mContext=mContext;
}
```

by using this context get font from asset you can use for font in place of Lato-Regular

```
   Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),  "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf");
   tv.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

hope this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a custom `TextView` and then assign that in your XML, you won't have to change anything in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` or `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

*Example of a custom `TextView`:*

```
public class GoBoldTextView extends TextView {
    AttributeSet attr;

    public GoBoldTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setCustomFont(context, attr);
    }

    public GoBoldTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public GoBoldTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        String customFont = null;
        TypedArray a = null;
        if (attrs != null) {
            a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.goBoldTextView);
            customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.goBoldTextView_customFont);
        }
        if (customFont == null) customFont = "fonts/Gobold Bold.ttf";
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
        if (a != null) {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("textView", "Could not get typeface", e);
            return false;
        }
        setTypeface(tf);
        return true;
    }
}
```

You'll then need to declare a `styleable` attribute in your `values` directory. So add an `XML` file called `attrs.xml` in your values directory and add the following code:

*Attrs.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="goBoldTextView">
        <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources >
```

Then simply in your `XML` row layout for your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

```
<packagename.GoBoldTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Custom Font"/>
```

Obviously you'll need to change the font that the class is directing to in the assets directory. Now if you just apply the XML reference to that class, the font will be applied to each one you have.

**Further Reading**:

- [Custom Fonts on Android — Extending TextView](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/custom-fonts-on-android-extending-textview)
- [Android Custom Font - TextView](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-custom-font-textview/)

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerViewFontActivity.java

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<fontModel> fontModelList;
fontModel[] fontModelObject;
String[] fontStyle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view_font);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    fontModelList = new ArrayList<>();  //initialized list
    fontModelObject=new fontModel[3];   //Array of model class
    fontStyle = new String[3];  //Array of String

    /* store font in String Array
    * */
    fontStyle[0] = "fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf";
    fontStyle[1] = "fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf";
    fontStyle[2] = "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf";

    /*
    *       store Array of String in variable of object and add object into List
    * */
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        fontModelObject[i] = new fontModel();
        fontModelObject[i].setFontStyle(fontStyle[i]);
        fontModelList.add(fontModelObject[i]);
    }

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));   //set layout
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new adapterDisplay(this,fontModelList));    //set Adapter
}
```

adapterDisplay.java

```
public class adapterDisplay extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterDisplay.ViewHolder> {

private List<fontModel> fontModelList;
private Context context;

public adapterDisplay(Context context, List<fontModel> fontModelList) {
    this.fontModelList = fontModelList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_display_activity, parent, false); //inflate layout in view
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontModelList.get(position).getFontStyle());  //get font style from list and store into typeface
    holder.textView.setTypeface(typeface);  //set typeface to textView
    holder.textView.setText("Custom Font --- " + fontModelList.get(position).getFontStyle());   //set text
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fontModelList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}}
```

fontModel.java

```
public class fontModel {
public String getFontStyle() {
    return fontStyle;
}

public void setFontStyle(String fontStyle) {
    this.fontStyle = fontStyle;
}

private String fontStyle;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Get your activity `context` from your adapter `constructor` and use it when creating instance of custom `typeface` in your adapter `constructor` by using `Typeface.createFromAsset()`.

**2.** In your adapter's `onBindViewHolder()`, set custom typeface to your textview `Arabictext`.

**Here is an example:**

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.NamesHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    Typeface customFont;

    public YourAdapter(Context context, ............) {

        this.mContext = context;

        // Get custom font 'roboto-light.ttf' from assets/fonts folder
        customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),  "fonts/your-arabic-font.ttf");

        ...............
        ...........................  
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position)   { 

        // Set custom font to Arabictext
        viewHolder.Arabictext.setTypeface(customFont);

        // Set values 
        viewHolder.Arabictext.setText("SOME_ARABIC_TEXT");
        viewHolder.Englishtext.setText("SOME_ENGLISH_TEXT");
        viewHolder.Translationtext.setText("SOME_TRANSLATION_TEXT");

        ...........
        ................. 
    }

    private static class NamesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView Arabictext, Englishtext, Translationtext;

        public NamesHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            Arabictext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.arabicTextView);
            Englishtext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.meaningTextView);
            Translationtext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.translationTextView);
       }
    }

}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Is this not bad for performance setting the font in `onBindViewHolder`?